# Signup user to ASP.NET Identity from Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

[image]

It has a problem not to send data, knowing that the code is used

```
public class ApiServices
{
    public async Task<bool> RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string confirmPassword)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var model = new RegisterBindingModel
        { Email = email,
       Password= password,
       ConfirmPassword= confirmPassword
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
  content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
  var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44323/api/Account/Register", content);
        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
}
```

An error message appears

> **System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.'**

And use (UWP).

Please help.

Comment: what is the InnerException?

Comment: COMException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect

Comment: That seems like a pretty big clue to me

Comment: I have attached a picture of the error that appears

Comment: "The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect" - google that, you clearly have a problem with your SSL cert

Comment: Based on your description, because the client cannot trust the certificate of the server. Did you used privated certificate or  self-signed root certificates? If so, you can refer to it thread about this issue:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3145#issuecomment-401888667